# Can all Spark SQL Builtin Functions be used directly on a dataframe without executing spark.sql("sql statement on temporary view")?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The below code works

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
df = spark.createDataFrame([(2020, 6, 26), (1000, 2, 29), (-44, 1, 1)],['Y', 'M', 'D'])
df.select("*",expr("make_date(Y,M,D) as lk")).show()
```

The below code fails with a message "cannot import name 'make_date' from 'pyspark.sql.functions'"

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, make_date
df = spark.createDataFrame([(2020, 6, 26), (1000, 2, 29), (-44, 1, 1)],['Y', 'M', 'D'])
df.select(make_date(df.Y,df.M,df.D).alias("datefield")).show()
```

And there are other functions like sum, mean etc that goes well with a dataframe groupBy clause .

```
df3.groupBy(df3.hair).agg(sum_(df3.age),max_(df3.age)).show()
```

I am confused here. Why are some functions not used directly with a dataframe column and only as a sql expression.

The spark documentation shows all functions executed as a sql statement and not on a dataframe column directly

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html

Comment: that's just because not every sql function has a corresponding implementation in pyspark

Comment: @mck I think this is the answer what I was looking for . So to work with dataframes , not all builtin functions can be used directly on a dataframe column .  We should use sql expression to apply it on a dataframe . How do we know which one can work directly  and which one needs a sql expression . Is there any documentation for that?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html and https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Comment: @mck thank you for the list .. But I have a question . In this list of functions how do we know which one works in both ways ,for example , the sum(column) function . It is there in both the list . 

Whichever way we are using it , either directly on a dataframe column or with a sql expression the function name has to be imported from pyspark.sql.functions . Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the pyspark functions correctly, you have to import them.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, max
```

or

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

However, in this case, the functions cannot be distinguished with the python native functions, `sum` and `max`. To avoid this,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
```

and use the pyspark function in such a way `f.sum` and `f.max`. If you do not import the functions correctly, the dataframe aggregation function also will not work.